# Count files from request with Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

The `SetupGet` for `Form` work, but the `Count` not work. How to resolve to  `Count` return the value expected?

```
var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);            
httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Form).Returns(form);
httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Files.Count).Returns(2);
```

Comment: It is not working because you are setting up the wrong mock

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are setting up the wrong mock. Apply the setup on the request mock.

```
var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

var requestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
requestMock.Setup(_ => _.Form).Returns(form);
requestMock.Setup(_ => _.Files.Count).Returns(2);

httpContextMock.Setup(_ => _.Request).Returns(requestMock.Object);
```

Just to prove the above works, I tested it like this

```
var context = httpContextMock.Object;

Assert.AreEqual(2, context.Request.Files.Count);
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test and it works if you access the request through the mock context.

```
    [Test()]
    public void Test()
    {
        var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

        httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Files.Count).Returns(2);

        var count = httpContextMock.Object.Request.Files.Count;
        Assert.AreEqual(2, count);
    }
```

As Nkosi suggested, however, you probably wanted to setup Files.Count on the requestMock itself.